# C++ 2D shared_ptr array initialize with abstract polymorphic type

Tags: c++, 2d, allocator

I have Polymorphic type that i need to initialize 2D array 
is like shared_ptr** Map

this is my initializer when there wasnt shared_ptr, can you tell me the solution to work ? 
Error is incompatible pointer types shared_ptr** and Game_Object***

```
Map = new shared_ptr<Game_Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) width_; i++)
        Map[i] = new shared_ptr<Game_Object>();
```

`Map = new shared_ptr<Game_Object>();` is `shared_ptr<Game_Object>*` 
and i need to get this "`shared_ptr<Game_Object>**`" how i do that?

Comment: First of all you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Secondly you need to copy-paste the full and complete compiler output to show us. Thirdly (but a little more unrelated to your direct problem) whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should *always* be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: There are also other problems as well with the very little code you show. Like for example that you will go out of bounds if `width_ > height_`, and probably other problems if `width_ < height_`.

Comment: vector for 2D is too slow

Comment: The code you show now doesn't really match, and especially it kind of makes the posted answer wrong. That's one of the reasons you should always make a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to have some code that exhibits your problem and that all can se and work with. Furthermore you can easily pre-allocate the vectors if that's what you worry about. Accessing a double- or even tripple-pointer will not be different from a vector of vectors.

Comment: For example, to make a dynamic variant of `std::shared_ptr<Game_Object> Map[width_][height_];` you do `std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Game_Object>>> Map(width_, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Game_Object>>(height_));` That's it, all memory for the vectors are allocated. All you need to do after that is initialize all the shared pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to get this `shared_ptr<Game_Object>**` how i do that?

`shared_ptr<Game_Object>**` is a raw pointer to raw pointer to shared pointer to `Game_Object`. Why do you need such complicated and confusing set up I dont know. But if you want to create one you can:

```
size_t x = 3, y = 4; // 3 x 4 2D array
std::shared_ptr<Game_Object> **arr = new std::shared_ptr<Game_Object>*[x]();
for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    arr[i] = new std::shared_ptr<Game_Object>[y]();
```

Of course you then need to give those shared pointers value:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < y; ++j)
        arr[i][j] = std::make_shared<Game_Object>();
```

And don't forget to `delete[]` allocated memory after you're done

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Some programmer dude. It's better to leave containers manage allocation business for you.

Moreover, you can have same-old built-in 2d array of shared_ptr on the heap with `modern` `code` if you **just** know the row width at compile time.

```
constexpr size_t const WIDTH = 200;

template<typename T, auto width>
using Arr2D_sptr = std::vector<std::array<std::shared_ptr<T>, width> >;

template<typename T>
auto make_row_sptr(size_t height) {
    return Arr2D_sptr<GameInvarient, WIDTH>{height};
}

int main()
{
    size_t height{100};
    auto my2d = make_row_sptr<GameInvarient>(height);
    // contagueous 2d of shared_ptr
    // and all pointed objects are already set 
    // from this point.
    // (objects are not contagueous)

    for (auto row : my2d) {
        for (auto sptr : row) {
            std::cout << sptr->x; // use object
        }
    }

    for (auto row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
        for (auto col = 0; col < WIDTH; ++col) {
            std::cout << my2d[row][col]->x; // use object
        }
    }

}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/czR3pZ